# Search for all video or audio files in Android

Tags: android, video, audio

I made a project like video/audio player in android.
I want to search all video and audio files available on the device, how can I do this?

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665601/search-a-all-video-or-audio-file-in-android

Comment: The previous link isn't working. I need a app to "Search for all video or audio files in Android".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **content provider** to query the **media store**, see the documentation at

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html